# Permission Issue while running a job which has @database_user_name

Tags: sql-server, jobs

I have sql job script I have mentioned @database_user_name. User has db_owner role and login has sysadmin role.

But the job is failing with error message

> Message
> Executed as user: intuser. The user does not have permission to perform this action. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 297).  The step failed.

Job procedure is failing when using msdb.dbo.syscategories table or DBCC SQLPERF(logspace) commands.

What is the issue and how to overcome this?

granted db_owner permission to user and login has sysadmin role. Still it showing permission issue.
Sample Job script

```
USE [msdb]
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'SQLdbjob', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=0, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'No description available.', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'TestLogin', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Verify.', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=1, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=' exec InsertspSQLPerf', 
        @database_name=N'AdventureWorks2019', 
        @database_user_name='testloginuser',
        @flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, @name=N'syspolicy_purge_history_schedule', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @freq_type=4, 
        @freq_interval=1, 
        @freq_subday_type=1, 
        @freq_subday_interval=0, 
        @freq_relative_interval=0, 
        @freq_recurrence_factor=0, 
        @active_start_date=20080101, 
        @active_end_date=99991231, 
        @active_start_time=20000, 
        @active_end_time=235959, 
        @schedule_uid=N'e63973f1-0bee-4097-962f-b5d1ec12adb4'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:
GO
```

Comment: There isn't enough information for us to even begin to guess here. YOu need to include a lot more information on what it is you've done, and when this error occurs.

Comment: what info do you need

Comment: The SP code, you may be doing something in the SP that required elevated permissions.

Comment: Create a sample job using script. In script msdb.dbo.sp_add_job parameters pass owner_login_name(should have sysadmin role inorder to pass database_user_name), in msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep parameters pass database_user_name. Give @database_user_name any permission required to run command.

Comment: Triple check that `testloginuser` has enough permissions to execute the `InsertspSQLPerf` procedure. If possible, log in as the user and run the procedure manually.

Comment: So take the script in my "answer", verify that it works for you too, then change the stored procedure to match your own and continue troubleshooting.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft sure will try it and let you know.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I have added the comments in your answer

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I was able to run the proc separately. The proc has DBCC SQLPERF(logspace) command. When used in job it failed.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me with this setup.

```
use AdventureWorks2019

go
create login TestLogin with password = '<some password>'
alter server role sysadmin add member TestLogin
go

create user testloginuser without login
create table foo(id int)
go
create procedure InsertspSQLPerf
as
begin
  insert into foo(id) values (1)
end
go
grant exec on InsertspSQLPerf to testloginuser
go
```

> DBCC SQLPERF(logspace)

Requires server-level permissions, which aren't available when impersonating a database principal.  You can accomplish this with a [signed stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-signing-stored-procedures-with-a-certificate?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: David this script worked. My proc has DBCC SQLPERF(logspace) command. when placed this command, it is failing with that error. But I was able to execute the proc separately with that login.

Comment: David I have added select * from msdb.dbo.syscategories in my proc. and ran the job and this was the error meassage, Executed as user: testloginuser. The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'syscategories', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 229).  The step failed. 0 20230703 110714